# Java - Most efficient way to create a graph of strings

Tags: java, graph, hashmap

I have been tasked with the following:

> Read a list of words in from a text file and input them into a graph.
>   And then perform some analysis on the graph.
>
> Words can match if any of the following are true
>
> 1. Insert a single new letter somewhere
> 2. Delete a single letter
> 3. Reverse the letters
> 4. Swap characters at 2 different positions`

My thought was to throw them into a hash map and if all of the above checks fail use linear probing to add them to a new spot in the table.

Is there any more efficient or easier ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Can I ask what context this is for?

This is quite a difficult problem, actually. You're looking for (for the most part) strings with a [minimum edit distance](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/med.pdf) of 1. One of the approaches to solve this problem is to create a [nondeterministic finite automata](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~goddard/texts/theoryOfComputation/3a.pdf). Depending on how large your data set you have, and what this is for, the solution you need might get pretty complex

Comment: The task is not entirely clear, IMHO. At least the roles of the graph and the meaning of "match" could be elaborated. I could imagine that the words should be *nodes* of the graph, and there should be an *edge* between two words if they "match" according to one of the 4 points (or maybe 4 *types* of edges, one for each match type?).

Comment: A project, he said our implementation has to be efficient.I have written all of the tests above, except now i need to start generating the graph based on the words i read in and the tests on them.

Comment: What type of project? What's the goal? Is the goal to complete a homework assignment? To spellcheck user inputs? To compare sequences of DNA across species?